# For Loop Incorrectly Inserting Repeating Values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a form which will allow a maximum of 10 contacts. I am using variables to find the fields contactName, contactEmail, contactType, then check if values are entered and insert them via a stored procedure.

The problem I'm having is that if I enter two names, it inserts both twice. If I enter three names, it inserts all three, three times, etc. What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: the `ID`, `EffectiveDate` and `Activity` will be the same for all contacts entered.

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand3 = new SqlCommand())
    {
        for (int i = 1; (i <= contactCount && i <= 10); i++)
        {
            _contactNameTextBox = FindControl("ContactName" + i + "TextBox") as TextBox;
            _contactEmailTextBox = FindControl("ContactEmail" + i + "TextBox") as TextBox;
            _contactTypeDropDownList = (FindControl("ContactType" + i + "DropDown") as DropDownList);

            if (_contactTypeDropDownList.SelectedValue != "")
            {
                sqlCommand3.CommandText = "usp_ContactsUpdate";
                sqlCommand3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCommand3.Connection = sqlConnection;
                sqlCommand3.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", id);
                sqlCommand3.Parameters.AddWithValue("EffectiveDate", effectiveDate);
                sqlCommand3.Parameters.AddWithValue("Activity", "Add");

                sqlCommand3.Parameters.AddWithValue("ContactName", _contactNameTextBox.Text.Trim());
                sqlCommand3.Parameters.AddWithValue("ContactEmail", _contactEmailTextBox.Text.Trim());
                sqlCommand3.Parameters.AddWithValue("ContactType", _contactTypeDropDownList.SelectedValue);

                sqlCommand3.ExecuteNonQuery();

                sqlCommand3.Parameters.Clear();
            }
        }
        Label1.Text = "Done";
    }
}
```

EDIT: here is `usp_ContactsUpdate`

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_ContactsUpdate
    @ID int,
    @EffectiveDate date,
    @Activity nvarchar(10),
    @ContactType nvarchar(10),
    @ContactName nvarchar(75),
    @ContactEmail nvarchar (75)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Contacts_Pending (ID, EffectiveDate, Activity, ContactType, ContactName, ContactEmail)
    VALUES (@ID, @EffectiveDate, @Activity, @ContactType, @ContactName, @ContactEmail)
END
```

Comment: Hard to say, to much is missing here. Did you step through your code, how often is the loop iterated? What is the value of `contactCount` What does the stored procedure do?

Comment: The loop is actually adding new parameters to the existing ones every time. Don't use `AddWithValue`. Add the parameters alone *outside* of the loop and just set their values inside the loop, eg `sqlCommand3.Parameters["ContactType"]=_contactTypeDropDownList;`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The parameters are cleared at the end of the loop.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in `usp_ContactsUpdate` given that the ID is the same for all 3.

Comment: @derpirscher The loop is iterated multiple times. I see 2x for two contacts, 3x when three contacts entered. Also, contactCount is shown in the above example, its part of the for loop, so you can see in the example it starts at 1and goes up to 10. What other information would you like?

Comment: So the number of iterations matches your expectiations? If that's the case, I suspect the error is in `usp_ContactsUpdate` ...

Comment: @DStanley usp_ContactsUpdate accepts one of each value. I see that it is being called each time something is inserted. So if two contacts, its being called 4x (2x for each). If three contacts it's being called 9x (3x for each). I'm just not seeing why it's doing that.

Comment: @derpirscher I wrote that incorrectly. If two contacts, its being called 4x (2x for each). If three contacts it's being called 9x (3x for each). I'm just not seeing why it's doing that.

Comment: Well, thus my question what is the *ACTUAL VALUE*  of `contactCount` and where does this value come from?

Comment: @derpirscher I apologize, I was thinking you were asking about i. contactCount is determined based on how many contact fields are declared. My form is dynamic so that initially only 1 is declared, if someone enters a value then a second is declared, etc. so contactCount will be at least 1 and always 10 or less.

Comment: The loop looks reasonable - it's not clear what `usp_ContactsUpdate` does to see if the duplication is caused by the logic there, possibly because you're using the same IDs each time.

Comment: @DStanley The stored procedure is pretty basic and just does a simple insert each iteration, accepting one of each value. I have updated my original question with the stored procedure as well for reference. As it accepts only one of each value and I can seeing in SQL profiler that it is being called too many times, I suspect the issue is with my C# but I'm just not seeing where.

Comment: I think you're going to have to run it in the debugger and put a breakpoint on the `ExecuteNonQuery` to see how  much it get called. I can't see anything with the loop that would indicate it gets called multiple times with the same value.  Or as suggested above, create a new command within the loop instead of reusing it.

Comment: Attach a debugger set a breakpoint for instance on `sqlConnection.Open()` and inspect the value of `contactCount` if that meets your expectations. Nothing in your stored procedure suggests that it will insert multiple items at once. Nothing in your loops suggests that it will run more often with the same parameters. So the error is either that `contactCount` is wrong or that this whole codeblock you are showing us is repeatedly called.  (for instance in an eventhandler that is fired multiple times?)

Comment: @derpirscher You are absolutely correct. I had a for loop in a codeblock before this, that was causing it to be fired multiple times. If you would leave your last comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in your stored procedure suggests that it will insert multiple items at once. Nothing in your loop suggests that it will run more often with the same parameters.

So the error is either that `contactCount` is not what you think it is or that this whole C# codeblock you are showing is repeatedly called. For instance it may be called from an eventhandler that fires multiple times or it may be within an other loop that runs multiple times.

Attach a debugger set a breakpoint for instance on `sqlConnection.Open()` and inspect the value of `contactCount` if it meets your expectations. If that's the case, also check how often that breakpoint is hit ... If everything worked as expected, it should be hit only once ...

Comment: Thank you. I had gotten so focused on this being an issue in my code posted above, I completely missed that my code block before that, also had a For loop which was causing this to be fired multiple times.